# How to find untranslated strings. NSLocalizedString()

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, localization

I'm using **NSLocalizedString()** for all localization stuff. The project is very big. We support many languages. Is there a way that I can easily extract strings that are not in the Localizable.strings but were wrapped with NSLocalizedString.

**Example.**
Let's say I have somewhere in my code:

```
NSString *message = NSLocalizedString(@"Sample message");
```

But developer forgot to put this string in Localizable.strings files, so it won't be translated. Is there a way to extract untranslated strings from the source code?

Also, I don't want to use **genstrings** tool. I already have a very big NSLocalizable.strings files. genstrings tool generates a new one with all strings wrapped with NSLocalizedString removing all former translations, which I do not want. I just want to extract untranslated strings and NOT ALL the strings marked with NSLocalizedString().

Thanks,
Rafal

Answer (score 5):

Check out the [genstrings](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/Strings/Strings.html) tool, that does exactly this. The genstrings tool is a command line tool delivered with XCode.

Try merging the genstrings generatet strings file with your existing one using the FileMerge tool in XCode (XCode > Open Developer Tool).

Comment: I already have a very big NSLocalizable.strings files. genstrings tool generates a new one with all strings wrapped with NSLocalizedString removing all former translations, which I do not want. I just want to extract untranslated strings and NOT ALL strings marked with NSLocalizedString().

Comment: Try merging the genstrings generatet strings file with your existing one using the FileMerge tool in XCode (XCode > Open Developer Tool).

Comment: I don't want to merge. I have to many languages to do it manually and play one by one with merging tool. I want a list with untranslated strings. That's all.

Comment: i've used genstrings to generate the strings file, but I still don't know how to find out the strings that I forgot to put in NSLocalizedString() methods.